# Miracast on Windows 10

Tags: windows, protocols

Is there any method add the Miracast protocol support to a Windows 10 portable device?
My portable (EliteBook 8560w) unit is Bluetooth and WiFi enabled, running Windows 10 Enterprise.
We have a few projectors that understand Miracast plus a dongle that brings the protocol to any standard HDMI TV.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

miracast is supported on windows10， the name is widi。
you can win+K to open the miracast feature.

some low version of win10 is not support widi.
you can update you win10 function.

some low wifi driver is not support widi
you can update you wifi driver

Answer (score 0):

Miracast protocol is implemented on windows 10 (software). That message says your hardware do not support Wifi-p2p which is the link between source and sink miracast uses. After that pairing miracast is simply a rtsp stream protocol.

Check this issue https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/issues/103 to understand internals of miracast protocol